# Can I redirect page from "Dynamic Link Not Found" page?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

If there is no dynamic link in the url, the page says "Dynamic Link Not Found". Can I redirect to the home page from this page? Or can I change the content of this page?

Comment: Did you figure something out?

Comment: Hey, do you find any solution for this?